# Magento paypal admin configuration not working

Tags: paypal, magento-1.7, magento

I have magento 1.7 installation, 
and it has many extensions installed, the problem is the paypal logo under **configuration > sales** not showing and the paypal settings are showing in completely on payment method admin config page. i try to access this by using url

**http://hellteam.bizarsoftware.com.au/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/payment/**
above one redirects to admin area

but still no luck

**i remove all core files and admin theme files and replace with new ones**, but no luck yet.. anyone has a idea about this.. please save me
thank you

Comment: This sounds like a question for Magento's support resources, not Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is for programming questions

Comment: In magento 1.7+ all payment methods been moved to single page